# Unable to install Intel HD graphics driver for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I am unable to install Intel Graphic driver in KUbubtu. I have install "Intel Graphic Update tool for Linux", but it says distribution not supported.

Log:

```
Checking if Intel graphics card available...
  • checking for i915 module in /sys/module
  • i915 module found
Checking if Intel graphics card available... OK
Retrieving information from 01.org...
  • fetching https://download.01.org/gfx/ilg-config.cfg
  • saving to /home/alok/.ilg-config
  • fetched 1626 bytes
  • fetched 9818 bytes
  • fetched 12301 bytes
  • looking up [Ubuntu bionic] configuration
Retrieving information from 01.org... OK
Checking distribution... Failed
```

System info:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04 LTS"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intel has discontinued the tool. Now the driver comes directly in the LTS distros of Ubuntu and Fedora.

> Better processes are yielding faster inclusion and users will notice Fedora 27 and Ubuntu 17.10 and beyond are very current. Therefore, we are discontinuing the Update Tool as of version 2.0.6.
>
> The final version 2.0.6 of the update tool was targeted specifically at both Ubuntu* 17.04 and Fedora* 26.

#### Reference

- [Update Tool | 01.org](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/update-tool)
- [Intel Axes its Linux Graphics Update Tool - OMG! Ubuntu!](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/03/intel-graphics-update-tool-discontinued)